# Search suggestion box: each row has a white background and white text

Tags: android, android-styles, searchview, search-suggestion

Any idea's on how to change the style for the suggestion box? I'm targeting sdk version 16.

I tryed defining a style for the searchview(reference: android-developers.blogspot.be/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) with a suggestionRowLayout item but it has no effect.

```
 <style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="suggestionRowLayout">@layout/search_suggestion_row</item>
 </style>
```

Image:
http://s22.postimg.org/p353knca9/suggestions.jpg

Image onClick Row: http://s18.postimg.org/5w0fuf0o9/seard.jpg

**useful info**

compileSdkVersion 22

buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

*dependencies*

com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0

com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0

*App Theme*

Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: Are you using a Toolbar?

Comment: Nope, the supportActionBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using android.Widget.SearchView instead of **android.support.v7.widget.SearchView**

menu.xml

```
app:actionViewClass="android.Widget.SearchView"
```

should be

> app:actionViewClass="**android.support.v7.widget.SearchView**"

and in my Fragment class I Imported the wrong package.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the view properties in the xml suggestions that you are probably inflating on the `newView()` method in your suggestions cursor adapter.

Comment: I'm using a searchable configuration file so I don't have a suggestions cursor adapter.